How do I show $y\in B(x,\delta)\implies B(y, \delta-||y-x||_{\infty})\subseteq B(x,\delta)$?
This is from "Supplement to Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler. The definition of $B(x,\delta)$ is reproduced below.

For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta>0$, the open cube $B(x,\delta)$ is defined by $B(x,\delta)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:||y-x||_\infty<\delta\}$.

I can convince myself of this implication intuitively by taking $n=1$ but am unsure how to formalise this. I know it's elementary but I've been stuck on it and would appreciate some help. Thanks for considering my question!

This has to follow from the triangle inequality.

Ix $z\in B(y;\delta-|y-x|)$ then $|x-z|\leq|z-y|+|y-x|<\ldots$

This is in fact true in general for any metric; specifically, if $y \in B_d (x, \delta)$ (equivalently, $d (x, y) < \delta$), then $B_d (y, \delta - d (x, y)) \subseteq B_d (x, \delta)$.
To prove it, let $z \in B_d (y, \delta - d (x, y))$. Then $d (y, z) < \delta - d (x, y)$. By the triangle inequality, we have that $d (z, x) \le d (z, y) + d (y, x) < (\delta - d (x, y)) + d (x, y) = \delta$. This shows that $z \in B_d (x, \delta)$. Since $z$ was arbitrary, $B_d (y, \delta - d (x, y)) \subseteq B_d (x, \delta)$.
In your specific case, you are using the metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by the "infinity norm"; i.e. $d (x, y) = ||y - x||_\infty$.

Very clear answer, thanks. What made you think of using the triangle inequality here?

@Leon Glad to help. We want to show that $z$ is contained in $B_d (x, \delta)$, or $d (x, z) < \delta$. Since we can bound $d (x, y)$ and $d (y, z)$, this is a good indication that triangle inequality can help.
